# Instance subclass field using parent protected constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, field, protected

Simplified situation

```
public class A {
    protected A() { }
    protected A Make() { return new A(); }
}

public class B : A {
    A a = new A(); //inaccessible due to protection level
    B b = new B();

    private B()
    {
        A c = new A();//inaccessible due to protection level
        a = new A(); //inaccessible due to protection level
        a = Make();
    }
}
```

Why it's impossible to create instance of A in class B using class A protected constructor?

In my mind protected constructor is like protected method so it should be possible to run it in subclass.

Comment: for calling base constructor you can `private B() : base()`

Comment: can you provide _full_ error message?

Comment: hm, i get another error: _Cannot access protected member 'A.A()' via a qualifier of type 'A'; the qualifier must be of type 'B' (or derived from it)_

Comment: Full message in VS Community 2015: "Error CS0122 'A.A()' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why it's impossible to create instance of A in class B using class A
>   protected constructor?

You **can't** call a protected constructor using the `new` modifier because the purpose of a *protected constructor* is that it can only be called from a derived classes point of view, thus not visible from the "outside".

The compiler doesn't infer the call to `new A()` is being done from an instance of `B`. That is why the constructor syntax is available, to guarantee a convention of how to call base constructors.

You *can call* `A` constructor when declaring a constructor for `B` :

```
public B(string foo) : base(foo)
```

This is what actually is being done on your behalf for a default constructor. For example:

```
public class A {}
public class B : A
{
    public B() {}
}
```

Will yield the following IL:

```
// Methods
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void .ctor () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x205a
    // Code size 7 (0x7)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: call instance void A::.ctor() <--- This.
    IL_0006: ret
} // end of method B::.ctor
```

One hackish way (I would avoid doing that) is to create such an instance can be achieved with `Activator.CreateInstance` overload which accepts a `bool` flag indicating the constructor is non-public:

```
var b = (B)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(B), nonPublic: true);
```

Comment: but in OP, `B` class have field for base class, and try init it.

Comment: @Grundy Exactly, he can't do that. That's what I state in my answer :)

Comment: possibly, i just missed main from your answer :-) i though you say just about calling `A` constructor as base for `B` and not as init field

Comment: So it means that I can only use parent class protected constructor by using `:base()` in subclass?

Comment: @JCode Yes, you can. That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov I asked if it is the only case in which I can use the protected constructor.

Comment: Yes, you can only invoke it via your own constructor declaration.

Answer (score 3):

You can make constructor `A` [`protected internal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

```
public class A
{
    protected internal A() { }
    protected A Make() { return new A(); }
}
```

So the type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a ***derived class*** in another assembly.

Have a look at this link for more details: [`Many Questions: Protected Constructors`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/peterhal/2005/06/29/many-questions-protected-constructors/).

Answer (score 2):

`protected` members are accessible in a derived class (subclass) only through an instance reference of the type of the derived class (or a further derived class).

Here is an example with methods instead of constructors:

```
class B
{
  protected void M() { }
}
class C : B
{
  void X()
  {
    M(); // OK, same as this.M()
  }
  void Y(C otherC)
  {
    otherC.M(); // OK
  }
  void Z(B otherB)
  {
    otherB.M(); // compile-time error CS1540
  }
}
```

So in the above example, you can call `M` on a `C` inside `C`, but you cannot call `M` on a `B` inside `C`.

Your example with instance constructors is analogous. A `new` object expression is like calling an instance member (the instance constructor) on a (new) object of the type written after `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify code to

```
a = this.Make();
```

Hope it can help you understand code better. Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx)

> A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

So when you call `this.Make()`, you are accessing `protected constructor` in `derived class instances`. When you call `new A()` inside `class B`, current instance `this` and new instance to be created are two different instances. You're actually accessing `A`'s constructor outside `A` or `A`'s derived class.

Comment: @Grundy, I didn't say `Make` not work. I want OP to understand `this` in the context.